# How can I split a column from an Eloquent model into 2 columns in a FilamentPHP resource table?

Tags: laravel, filamentphp

In my panel (FilamentPHP v3),

I need to display a database column in 2 separate panel columns. It always contains 10 characters, 5 to be in each column.

The code attempt below displays only one of the columns. It doesn't seem to allow repeat calls by TextColumn::make on same model column.

```
TextColumn::make('scode')->state(
  function (Model $rec) {
    return substr($rec->scode, 0, 4);
  }
),
TextColumn::make('scode')->state(
  function (Model $rec) {
    return substr($rec->scode, 5, 9);
  }
),
```

Is there a way to do this without having 2 columns in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed not use the same column twice, but since you already defined the state (based on the record), you don't need to.
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/columns/getting-started#calculated-state

You can change the names into anything you'd like, as long as they're not the same. (If you want to) you can make the names prettier by using labels.

```
TextColumn::make('scode1')->state(
  function (Model $rec) {
    return substr($rec->scode, 0, 4);
  }
)->label('SCode 1'),
TextColumn::make('scode2')->state(
  function (Model $rec) {
    return substr($rec->scode, 5, 9);
  }
)->label('SCode 2'),
```